# Nested subroutines and Scoping in Perl

Tags: perl, scope, nested, subroutine

I'm writing Perl for quite some time now and always discovering new things, and I just ran into something interesting that I don't have the explanation to it, nor found it over the web.

```
sub a {
   sub b {
     print "In B\n";
   }
}
b();
```

how come I can call `b()` from outside its scope and it works?

I know its a bad practice to do it, and I dont do it, I use closured and such for these cases, but just saw that.

Comment: You could only enforce this type of scoping with OOP

Comment: something like closures will help you ;) it is not the same you are asking about, but another good implementation of subroutines.

Comment: Perl v5.20 has [lexical named subroutines](http://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2015/01/named-lexical-subroutines/)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Subroutines are stored in a global namespace at compile time. In your example `b();` is short hand for `main::b();`. To limit visibility of a function to a scope you need to assign an anonymous subroutines to a variable.

Both named and anonymous subroutines can form closures, but since named subroutines are only compiled once if you nest them they don't behave as many people expect.

```
use warnings;
sub one {
    my $var = shift;
    sub two {
        print "var: $var\n";
    }
}
one("test");
two();
one("fail");
two();
__END__
output:
Variable "$var" will not stay shared at -e line 5.
var: test
var: test
```

Nesting named subroutines is allowed in Perl but it's almost certainly a sign that the code is doing someting incorrectly.

Comment: That is an interesting example. How do you explain that it does not update `$var` the second time? Curiously, if you remove the line `one("test")`, it complains about the undefined variable, but then `one("fail")` ***is*** allowed to update `$var`. Undefined behaviour?

Comment: I believe I found the answer in [perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html#Function-Templates).

Comment: @TLP, `sub two {}` is `BEGIN { *two = sub {} }`, so it captures over the `$var` that existed when it was compiled. `my` is basically a `new` that occurs on scope exit, so `two`'s `$var` becomes distinct from `one`'s `$var` after the first run of `$one`.

Comment: So is this behavior of the sample code in this answer considered a feature, or just a byproduct of the nature of perl's symbol table?  Because if I saw that code written down someplace, and I would have never guessed that it would behave that way.  Just curious.

Answer (score 11):

The "official" way to create nested subroutines in perl is to use the `local` keyword. For example:

```
sub a {
    local *b = sub {
        return 123;
    };
    return b();  # Works as expected
}

b();  # Error: "Undefined subroutine &main::b called at ..."
```

The perldoc page [perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html#Function-Templates) has this example:

```
sub outer {
    my $x = $_[0] + 35;
    local *inner = sub { return $x * 19 };
    return $x + inner();
}
```

"This has the interesting effect of creating a function local to another function, something not normally supported in Perl."

Answer (score 7):

The following prints `123`.

```
sub a {
    $b = 123;
}

a();
print $b, "\n";
```

So why are you surprised that the following does too?

```
sub a {
    sub b { return 123; }
}

a();
print b(), "\n";
```

Nowhere is any request for `$b` or `&b` to be lexical. In fact, you can't ask for `&b` to be lexical (yet).

```
sub b { ... }
```

is basically

```
BEGIN { *b = sub { ... }; }
```

where `*b` is the symbol table entry for `$b`, `@b`, ..., and of course `&b`. That means subs belong to packages, and thus can be called from anywhere within the package, or anywhere at all if their fully qualified name is used (`MyPackage::b()`).

Answer (score 2):

Subroutines are defined during compile time, and are not affected by scope. In other words, they cannot truly be nested. At least not as far as their own scope is concerned. After being defined, they are effectively removed from the source code.

Comment: Well, they can be nested, just not lexically scoped.

Comment: @briandfoy It seems there is more to it than I knew.. found a very cryptical explanation in [perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html#Function-Templates). Is this behaviour intentional? What possible use could it have?

Comment: @briandfoy - "I assume by 'can be nested' you mean 'can be physically placed inside another sub's code'; as opposed to 'can have semantics affected by such nested placement'", correct?

Comment: @DVK In Ven'Tatsu's answer, the two subs are seemingly nested, at least as far as the variable is concerned. I tried it with `strict`, and it is valid code.

Comment: @DVK Yes, "nested" as inside a "{ }" block in the source code.

Comment: A long time ago I said subs couldn't be lexically scope. Now they can be, but it's an experimental feature: http://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2015/01/named-lexical-subroutines/